# PHP - POST and GET method on the same page

Tags: php

I would like to make a variable $find equal to $_POST['find'] if the user is landing on the page after using the POST method, but on the same page make $find equal to $_GET['find'] if the user is landing on the page after using the GET method.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$find = $_GET['find'];

$find = $_POST['find'];
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers... they all seem good/correct to me.  But they didn't solve the larger problem that I was trying to solve: implementing pagination.  I guess I'll just put pagination on the back burner for now.

Comment: Maybe you would find it useful to access a question about pagination basics in PHP.  I'm sure you will get a lot of answers as it's a well documented process.

Answer (score 12):

You should use the [`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) global variable.  It contains all the data from both $_GET and $_POST.

Alternatively, you could check the request method.

```
$find = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') ? $_GET['find'] : $_POST['find'];
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`$_REQUEST` variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` where the [`variables_order` option](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) defines the order in which the variables are read and overwrite already existing contents.

So you can either use `$_REQUEST['find']` (considering that a cookie value for `find` will override both POST and GET). Or you implement it on your own:

```
if (isset($_GET['find'])) {
    $find = $_GET['find'];
}
if (isset($_POST['find'])) {
    $find = $_POST['find'];
}
```

With that code `$find` will be `$_GET['find']` if it exists unless there is a `$_POST['find']` that will override the value from `$_GET['find']`.

Answer (score 2):

Literally what you're asking for is:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
   $find = $_POST['find'];
} else {
   $find = $_GET['find'];
}
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
   $find = $_REQUEST['find'];
```

$_REQUEST is a combination of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_REQUEST['find'] to get the combined information from $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

[$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) returns an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE (You can change the default contents with the [php.ini "request_order" directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order))

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['find'])){
    $find = $_GET['find'];
}elseif(isset($_POST['find'])){
    $find = $_POST['find'];
}else{
    $find = null;
}
// do stuff with $find;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which method was used then just use the [$_REQUEST](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) super global.

If it matter which method was used:

```
$find = isset($_GET['find']) ? $_GET['find'] : false;
if ($find === false) {
   $find = isset($_POST['find']) ? $_POST['find'] : '';
   // do a POST-specific thing
}
else {
    // do a GET-specific thing
}
```